# Javascript Methods/Objects

Tags: javascript

I think I finally wrapped my head around understanding how methods, constructor functions, and objects work. Could someone please review my code, and let me know if I using the correct names and syntax? Thanks a ton!

```
function objectConstructor (arg1, arg2) {
     this.property1 = arg1;
     this.property2 = arg2;
     this.methodName = functionName;
}
function functionName() {
     console.log(this.property1 + ' ' + this.property2);   
}

var object1 = new objectConstructor('value1','value2');

console.log(object1.property1);
console.log(object1.methodName());
```

Comment: Why don't you just paste this into a console and see if it runs? Since you're only asking about *syntax*.

Comment: By the convention, constructor functions names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: you didn't understand that javascript is a prototype based language and in the way you do it it's very memory intensive and slow. [Prototype-based_programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)

Comment: I agree and understand javascript is a prototype based language. This example was just for my own understanding on how everything works as a whole. I would never uses these names in a project or anything that would be insane! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This answer should explain the basics of constructor functions and prototype:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1):

Methods of Javascript classes should be defined as prototype:

```
var CustomObject = function (arg1, arg2) {
     this.property1 = arg1;
     this.property2 = arg2;
};

CustomObject.prototype.functionName = function() {
     console.log(this.property1 + ' ' + this.property2);   
};

var object1 = new CustomObject("value1","value2");
```

Everything else seems fine to me though.

Comment: Messing with the Object prototype is considered bad practice.

Comment: You're absolutely right thanks Manuel! I'm still learning prototypes, but thank you for the example.

Comment: @DanMan Object should be the name of a custom type here. I forgot that there was the javascript-"Object".

Answer (score 0):

Use prototype functions. Else your inner functions get copied with every instance.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function()
{
    return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
}

var person1 = new Person('foo', 'bar');
console.log(person1.getFullName());
```

There are many other patterns which for example prevent the pollution of the global scope or allow a more class like approach. (Object literal, Module Pattern, Self-Executing Anonymous Functions)

The same example with the module pattern:

```
var Person = (function()
{
    var Person = function(firstName, lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Person.prototype.getFullName = function()
    {
        return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
    }

    return Person;

})();

var person1 = new Person('foo', 'bar');
console.log(person1.getFullName());
```

Comment: @sneak972 I've add a module pattern example.